# how to pass $db->insert_id from one form to other on the same page

Tags: php

I have this form which insert my products information to my database and on the same page I have another form which insert images for the same project on another table on my database and I have 5 filed for uploading images, now when I insert my product information I create a `$db->insert_id` to use it when I upload the images on the other form to define the images id to call them later.
see the code first

```
<?php       
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $target = '../images/Projects/';
    $pro_name = $_POST['pro_name'];
    $pro_address = $_POST['pro_address'];
    $area_from = $_POST['area_from'];
    $area_to = $_POST['area_to'];
    $pro_kind = $_POST['pro_kind'];
    $pro_finish = $_POST['pro_finish'];
    $pro_small_rooms = $_POST['pro_small_rooms'];
    $pro_big_rooms = $_POST['pro_big_rooms'];
    $pro_receptions = $_POST['pro_receptions'];
    $pro_small_bathrooms = $_POST['pro_small_bathrooms'];
    $pro_big_bathrooms = $_POST['pro_big_bathrooms'];
    $pro_description = $_POST['pro_description'];
    $proActivity=$_POST['propActivity'];

    $putData = "INSERT INTO project_info (id, pro_title, pro_address, pro_area_from, pro_area_to, pro_kind, pro_description, pro_finish, pro_big_rooms, pro_small_rooms, pro_reception, pro_big_bathroom, pro_small_bathroom, propActivity) values ( '', '$pro_name', '$pro_address', '$area_from', '$area_to', '$pro_kind', '$pro_description', '$pro_finish', '$pro_big_rooms', '$pro_small_rooms', '$pro_receptions', '$pro_big_bathrooms', '$pro_small_bathrooms', '$proActivity')";
    $result = $db->query( $putData ) or die ( $db->error );
    $projectID=$db->insert_id;
}

if(isset($_POST['submitImages'])){
    $target = '../images/Projects/';
    $num=1;
    foreach ($_FILES["img"]["error"] as $key => $error)
    {
        if ($error==UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
        {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"][$key];
            $name = $_FILES["img"]["name"][$key];
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$target/$name");

            $putData = "INSERT INTO projects_images (id, image, image_id)VALUE('', '$name', '$projectID')";
            $result = $db->query($putData)or die($db->error);
            if($result){
                echo "OK";
                }else{
                    echo"error";
                    }
        }

    }
    }
?>
```

now I have two submit for two forms on the same page so is it possible to pass `$db->insert_id` value to form two and if not how I can solve this.

Comment: **You are very open to SQL injection**. Use prepared statements and bind variables, or at *least* escape all user variables.

Comment: Thanks @h2ooooooo I going to do that later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let me get this straight.

> now I have two submit for two forms on the same page

what you want is for your page to hold 2 different forms

- form1: input product information (generates ID)
- form2: input associated to product images (associated to above product ID)

I will make some assumptions first

- the product info must be inserted first so the images can be associated afterwards
- the info is inserted and submitted, then the images are uploaded and submitted in a 2-step process
- you don't want this to happen, either...

  - all info should be sent at the same time (this means *all-in-one* form)
  - keep 2 forms but chain the submit execution so that the user seems like he is sending just one form.

Please gimme' some comments and I will gladly expand on your propositions

PD: btw, are we only supposed to use PHP?

### EDIT

This is a mockup skeleton script to show you an idea of what you can do

```
// some starter logic
if (isset($_POST['operation'])) switch ($_POST['operation']) {
  case 'createProject':
    // logic behind submitting this form
    // all goes well
    $selectedProyect = $someResultFromLogic_MaybeAnObjectThatHoldsAnId;
    break;
  case 'fileLoader':
    // logic behind submitting this form
    break;
  default: $msg = 'Unknown operation: '.$_POST['operation']; break;
}

if ($selectedProyect) {
  // the user has already submitted our project info form
  include 'fileLoaderForm.template.php';
} else {
  // the user is setting up a new project
  include 'createProyectForm.php';
}
```

Of course, this will get complicated fast when whatever you are trying to build gets big. There are frameworks that help you organize your code much better, I know of (and have used) MVC. I make my own MVCs of varying complexity but there are community driven projects out there that work out miracles. I suppose your next move is to do some more research

Comment: very good analysis. and I agree with your viewpoint, all I need is that the user can upload the first 5 images and when it's done he can upload another 5 images and etc... for this reason I am put two forms and I am welcoming any new ideas for this.

Comment: but what is the relationship between form1 and form2. Are these forms displayed at the same time? should they be? Is form1 supposed to be an insert/update form? once the user has made the insert, the form becomes a populated update form and form2 shows up as well? please expand on what the user sees or does

Comment: yes I was thinking about that too to make form1 and when the user submit form1 he see as next step form2 but this is a long way but you are right @hanzo2001 if there is any new idea please provide me with it

Answer (score 0):

As you process two separate forms you should

- or show selected project and assign projectid to images form hidden field
- or show new project form

Comment: what will be the value of the hidden field do you mean `$db->insert_id` this will be the value and then what I made it in two form so the admin can insert 5 images and then after finish he can upload another 5 images and etc...